# Como redimensionar imagem com largura fixa

Tags: php, matemática

Estou com dificuldades para redimensionar uma imagem para uma largura especifica, apenas consigo redimensionar proporcionalmente de acordo com largura ou altura.

Consigo apenas:

```
<?php

$original_width = x;
$original_height = y;

$redimensionar = 200;

// Novos valores
$width = 0;
$height = 0;

if ($original_width > $original_height) {
    $ratio = ($redimensionar / $original_width);
}
else {
    $ratio = ($redimensionar / $original_height);
}

$width = ($original_width * $ratio);
$height = ($original_height * $ratio);
```

O problema com isso é que a imagem poderá ter 200 de largura ou de altura, o que tenho que fazer e não consigo é deixar a largura sempre com 200 e a altura proporcional.

[EDITADO]

Quando fiz um código para redimensionar sempre com largura de 200, o calculo de ratio estava ao contrário, por isso estava trabalhando com apenas este acima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer que a imagem tenha sempre largura igual a 200 então sua nova largura deve ser 200 e a nova altura deve ser proporcional, ou seja igual a sua razão vezes a nova largura.

```
<?php

$original_width = x;
$original_height = y;

$redimensionar = 200;

// Novos valores
$width = 0;
$height = 0;

$ratio = ($original_height / $original_width);

$width = $redimensionar;
$height = ($width * $ratio);
```

Isso ocorre pois a razão `altura/largura` deve se manter constante (para a imagem escalar proporcionalmente) então se a nova largura é 200 a nova altura é obtida fazendo `largura * razão` que no caso é `200 * razão`.

Comment: Eu estava fazendo quase isso, meu código falhava porque eu estava calculando ($original_width / $original_height) quando é o contrário

Comment: Mas se você quer que a largura seja sempre 200 essa é forma. Ou você quer que a menor dimensão seja 200?

Comment: Seria sempre 200 de largura, o problema real era que meu calculo de ratio estava ao contrário

Comment: Entendi, que bom que você conseguiu resolver! :)