# Redimensionar Imagem

Tags: php, html

Preciso redimensionar para um tamanho fixo as imagens que vem do `getass` tentei no `html` mas as imagens tem tamanhos diferentes então cada uma fica de um tamanho. Queria setar um tamanho fixo para mostras essa imagem com o tamanho setado independente do tamanho da imagem original.

***Código:***

```
<td align="Center">
   <?php 
      echo '<img src="'.$objCheck->getass().'" class="" height="15%" width="15%">'; 
   ?>
</td>
```

Tem umas imagens que ficam em 90°graus para a direita e algumas normais. Não tem um jeito para padronizar isto também ?

Comment: Só coloca **width** e tira o **height** do HTML, assim ele redimensiona automaticamente de acordo com o comprimento.

Comment: Mas não use width=""... em percentagem porque ele não assume. Um comprimento ou uma altura fixa, nunca os dois para não deformar a imagem

Comment: Veja se essa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47448/como-redimensionar-imagem-com-largura-fixa?rq=1) te ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Use o atributo `style` ao invés de `width` e `height`. Para fixar o tamanho da imagem talvez você possa fazer o seguinte...

```
<td align="Center">
    <?php 
        echo '<img src="'.$objCheck->getass().'" class="" style="height:15em; width:15em">'; 
    ?>
</td>
```

A unidade `em` equivale a altura de uma linha (na verdade a altura da fonte). Ou se quiser mais específico use `px` para determinar o tamanho em pixels exatos.

## css